# How to display some of the JSON Data in select option using php?

Tags: php, arrays, json, foreach

I connect to an API and receive a JSON Data with PHP. After execute:

```
$countries= curl_exec($ch);
$jd_countries = json_decode($countries, TRUE);
print $countries;
```

The result of this is:

[image]

I would like to use for each to add the **country_id** and **name** to option value

So my code will be something like this:

```
<select name="country" class="form-control" >
    <?php foreach($jd_countries as $value){ ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $country_id;?>"><?php echo $name;?>
        </option> 
    <?php } ?>
</select>
```

I receive this:

> Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\account\index.php on line 28 Array
>
> Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\account\index.php on line 28 Array

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is `$jd_countries` ? And you never use `$value`, what is `$country_id` and `$name` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php foreach($jd_countries['data'] as $country){ ?>
   <option value="<?php echo $country['country_id'];?>"><?php echo $country['name'];?>
   </option>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Hi Denis. Thanks for your answer. I change my code and I receive this error: Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\account\index.php on line 27

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\account\index.php on line 27

Comment: hey yes, sorry I was trying to take the data like $jd_countries->data but it's an array not object so change it to $jd_countries['data']. I also have changed the answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert $countries to array

```
$jd_countries= json_decode($countries, TRUE);

<?php foreach($jd_countries->data as $country){ ?>
   <option value="<?php echo $country['country_id'];?>"><?php echo $country['name'];?>
   </option>
<?php } ?>
```